# Python socket still keeps incoming even after client terminates

Tags: python, sockets

I'm trying to achieve interprocess communication with socket. I have this code which acts as a socket server. When a message is received, the server broadcasts all the message to the other conntected clients.

```
from socket import AF_INET, gethostname, socket, SOCK_STREAM
import _thread as thread

clients = []

HOST = gethostname()
PORT = 33000
BUFFER_SIZE = 1024
ADDR = (HOST, PORT)

s = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM)
s.bind(ADDR)

def accept_client():
    while True:
        client, _ = s.accept()
        clients.append(client)
        print("Client accepted.")
        thread.start_new_thread(handle_client, (client, ))

def handle_client(client):
    while True:
        message = client.recv(BUFFER_SIZE)
        print("Incoming message: {}".format(message.decode('utf-8')))
        broadcast(message)

def broadcast(message):
    print("Broadcasting...")
    for c in clients:
        print("Broadcasting to {}".format(c))
        c.send(message)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    s.listen()
    print("Listening...")
    thread.start_new_thread(accept_client, ())
    try:
        while True:
            pass
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        print("Exited.")
        exit(0)
```

And here is a class for my client.

```
from socket import AF_INET, gethostname, socket, SOCK_STREAM
import _thread as thread

class SocketClient:
    buffer_size = 1024

    def __init__(self, host=gethostname(), port=33000):
        self.host = host
        self.port = port
        self.buffer_size = 1024
        self.s = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM)
        self.s.connect((self.host, self.port))

    def bind_callback(self, callback, args=()):
        thread.start_new_thread(self.receive, (callback, args))

    def receive(self, callback, args):
        while True:
            try:
                msg = self.s.recv(self.buffer_size).decode('utf-8')
                callback(msg, *args)
            except OSError as err:
                self.close()
                raise err
            except NameError:
                raise err

    def send(self, msg):
        try:
            self.s.send(msg.encode('utf-8'))
        except:
            self.close()

    def close(self):
        self.send('{clientClose}')
        self.s.close()
```

In other script which I've create the object of`SocketClient`, **there is an infinite amount of incoming socket after the script terminates** (by Ctrl+D in Python). The server script (which prints an attempt when an incoming socket is received) shows this repeatedly:

```
Incoming message: 
Broadcasting...
Broadcasting to <socket.socket fd=4, family=AddressFamily.AF_INET, type=SocketKind.SOCK_STREAM, proto=0, laddr=('127.0.1.1', 33000), raddr=('127.0.0.1', 44126)>
Broadcasting to <socket.socket fd=5, family=AddressFamily.AF_INET, type=SocketKind.SOCK_STREAM, proto=0, laddr=('127.0.1.1', 33000), raddr=('127.0.0.1', 44276)>
```

Observe that there appears to be no incoming messages.

My assumption is that I've failed to close the socket connection properly (before exiting). How can this be achieved? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Calling `client.recv(1024)` will block and return 1 to 1024 bytes *unless* the client disconnects, in which case it will return an empty bytestring:

```
def handle_client(client):
    while True:
        message = client.recv(BUFFER_SIZE)

        if not message:
            # client disconnected
            break

        ...
```